# PHP remove "reference" from a variable.

Tags: php, variables, reference

I have the code below. I want to change $b to use it again with values. If I do so it changes $a as well. How can I assign a value to $b again after previously assigning it as a reference to $a?

```
$a = 1;
$b = &$a;

// later
$b = null;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See explanation inline

```php
$a = 1;    // Initialize it

$b = &$a;  // Now $b and $a becomes same variable with 
           // just 2 different names  

unset($b); // $b name is gone, vanished from the context.
           //  But $a is still available

$b = 2;    // Now $b is just like a new variable with a new value.
           // Starting a new life.
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$a = 1;
$b = &$a;

unset($b);
// later
$b = null;
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @xdazz is correct, but just to add the following great example from the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/unset) which gives an insight into what PHP is doing under the hood.

In this example you can see that `$bar` within the function foo() is a static reference to a function scope variable.

Unsetting `$bar` removes the reference but doesn't deallocate the memory:

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    static $bar;
    $bar++;
    echo "Before unset: $bar, ";
    unset($bar);
    $bar = 23;
    echo "after unset: $bar\n";
}

foo();
foo();
foo();
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Before unset: 1, after unset: 23
Before unset: 2, after unset: 23
Before unset: 3, after unset: 23
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all: Creating a reference from `$a` to `$b` creates a connection (for the lack of a better word) between the two variables, so `$a` changing when `$b` changes is exactly the way it is meant to work.

So, assuming you want to break the reference, the easiest way ist

```
unset($b);
$b="new value";
```